# I transfer a picture folder from desktop to an imovie project in 10.0.3

Tags: mac, applications, desktop

How do I transfer a folder from desktop to an imovie 10.0.5 project?

Comment: What do you mean by folder?

Answer (score 1):

In iMovie you can import files. The option for this is located in the top of the iMovie screen.